# Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '167x167' pixels, in .png format when trying to upload app

Tags: ios, xcode, appicon

I successfully uploaded my app on Xamarin forms but after it was uploaded I received this in an email from apple:

"Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly `167x167` pixels, in .png format ."

So it wants an image in my resources file I suppose (not in info.plist icons as they are not asking for 167x there) but should I name it: Icon-83.5@2x.png or Icon-174.png?

Comment: Sounds like this might be your issue https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/184818/#Comment_184818

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've had this particular problem in the last couple of days.

The iPad icon didn't show within the `Info.plist` and kept giving the warning you're getting right now.

My fix was to manually add the icon `Icon-83.5@2x.png` to the resources folder ( as Prashant pointed out ) and add this to the `Info.plist`:

```
<key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
<array>
    <string>Icon-40.png</string>
    <string>Icon-40@2x.png</string>
    <string>Icon-40@3x.png</string>
    <string>Icon-60@2x.png</string>
    <string>Icon-60@3x.png</string>
    <string>Icon-76.png</string>
    <string>Icon-76@2x.png</string>
    <string>Icon-83.5@2x.png</string>
    <string>Icon-Small-40.png</string>
    <string>Icon-Small-40@2x.png</string>
    <string>Icon-Small.png</string>
    <string>Icon-Small@2x.png</string>
    <string>Icon-Small@3x.png</string>
</array>
```

I used to work with `Asset Catalog` but I couldn't get it to work with the `iPad Pro` icon.

Comment: You save me bro!! Bless you God!

Answer (score 19):

Go to **xcode** > select **Images.xcassets** > check **ipad** from the right menu at the top right > you will get new set of dimensions, now it's easy as fill your new app icons for each dimension.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9):

### Xcode 14.1 (14B47b)

You're getting this error because you have checked the `iPad` option. In my case, I had been developing my app on Xcode 13.x and then after the new version of Xcode 14.x I got this error.

So on **Xcode 14** there is no need to create app icons in various versions and put them inside `Images.xcassets`, just follow the steps:

1. Click on the `Images`:

   [image]
2. Then try to press <kbd>+</kbd> and choose iOS App icon:

   [image]
3. You will see it got changed by comparing it to the previous version, it only accepts one and only one 1024x png image.

   [image]

Now, clean your last build and build your app again.

**But** if still you want to use the previous version, you can click on `AppIcon` and then after choosing it, open the right panel of Xcode:

[image]

Then by choosing `All sizes` you would be able to see the previous version set.

Answer (score 4):

For the forum post Andres mentioned in the comments:

Rename the 167x167 icon file to `Icon-83.5@2x.png`, place it in the Resources folder, and make sure it has a build action of `BundleResource`.

See https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_resources/ for information about setting `BundleResource` option.

Answer (score 4):

**XCODE 13 2022**

In my case, the problem was default AppIcon is deprecated, then we need to use a new App Icon standard. As I publish apps to iPhone and iPad I need all the necessary icons. (This issue no appear when you check only one device(iPhone or iPad))
[image]

1. Go to Xcode >Images.xcassets> And select your App Icon from the assets list.
   [image]
2. Right-click on there, You can now see a menu list like that
   [image]
3. Select iOS>New iOS App Icon

   - Then you can find now a new "AppIcon" asset named "AppIcon-1"
   - There is a difference to "AppIcon" because It has more icons options(iPad icons size)
4. Remove "AppIcon" (OLD)
   [image]
5. Rename your "AppIcon-1" to "AppIcon"
   [image]

Now you can put the missing icon size.

Answer (score 1):

After trying many things, this is how I fixed the "Missing required icon" error messages:
Go to Solution->ProjectName.iOS->Asset Catalogs->Assets.

See "AppIcons" there?  We are going to delete it, BUT FIRST!  Find that same folder in your project files and copy it somewhere safe.  Now, delete the AppIcons asset in the project. Also delete the "Assets" catalog.

ProjectName.iOS right click select 'Clean'.  Go to physical project folder.  Delete the "bin" and "obj" folders.  Find the empty "Assets.xcassets" folder and delete it as well.

ProjectName.iOS->Asset Catalogs right click select "Add Asset Catalog".  It should automatically add an "AppIcons" entry.  Go through and set each of the image sizes, pointing to where you copied your images.  They will automatically be copied to the Assets.xcassets folder.  They will also generate hidden entries in the ProjectName.iOS.csproj file that will include the image in the final binary.  The entries look like this:

```
<ImageAsset Include="Assets.xcassets\AppIcons.appiconset\1024.png">
<Visible>false</Visible>
</ImageAsset>
```

Edit Info.plist.  Set the App Icons Source to "AppIcons".

ProjectName.iOS right click, select "Rebuild". ProjectName.iOS right click, select "Archive". Archive Manager > Distribute > App Store. Verify certificate. Enter Apple login name and App-Specific password to upload. Done!

Comment: P.S. the actual file names didn't matter.  Mine are named as "resolution".png.

Comment: These steps didn't work for me the first time, but when I also restarted both my Mac and Windows box prior to putting all the images back in, it worked. Also, for anyone else reading, my steps diverged from Mr_Engineer's in that I do not Archive from within Visual Studio. I simply go Project > Build and then use Project >Show IPA file on build server... and then use Transporter on the Mac to verify and upload.

Answer (score 0):

I use Visual Studio 2017 on a Windows machine with a MacBook connected to it. I have an Asset Catalog called images that contains an image set called AppIcons where I have posted all of the various required image sizes. I was getting the same error as medvedo except I was getting three errors for 3 different images sizes (2 for ipad and 1 for ipod as I recall) After a lot of searching I found the solution was to reference the Asset Catalog in the Info.plist file.

First I had to find the path that Xamarin was putting my asset catalog in. I did that by deploying the app to the MacBook and then using Finder I went to the Go menu and chose the Library folder (earlier in the day I Googled how to show hidden folders on the Mac) In the Library folder I found the Caches folder and in that I found Xamarin/mtbs/builds/myappname There I found that the folder was Images.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset. I say all of this knowing that it might always be in that folder but I had to look it up so I thought I would share in case it changes from installation to installation.

Once I knew the path and name I was able to add the following to my Info.plist file inside of  branch

XSAppIconAssets
  Images.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset

FYI - I have built and deployed this app to iTunes at least 4 times over the previous 8 months. I am not sure what I did, if anything, to cause the error to pop up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still facing issue with all the above process steps performed correctly.
Then please check you are logged into appstore connect using your browser and then try to publish it will and  work.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the app to be available for ipad and getting the same error just uncheck ipad from runner properties below version number

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old thread but if someone is running into this problem.

Nothing from the above worked for me.
I edited the Assets using Xcode adding only one icon --> replaced them with generated icons via finder, including the contents.json file --> Noticed that after reopening Xcode it still displayed only one icon.

After checking the path in Xcode I noticed it created another folder for the Assets under yourapppath/obj/Xcode/1/.

I replaced them there and was able to publish my app to the store.

Greetings

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).